# Xcode error Build input file cannot be found metadata-arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I developed an application with nativescript, for mobiles and now I am trying to build the IPA file for the release.
Right now I am facing an issue that I can't solve, I try to launch "build" form Xcode panel but I always get this error :

"Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/username/Documents/name_of_app/tuto-app/platforms/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/metadata-arm64.bin'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?"

I tried ns run ios it works fine on simulator, I also tried ns build ios but I get the same error.

I work with Xcode version : 12 recently updated.

I tried workspace setting > build mode > legacy but I have an error that says "unable to create directory"

Has anyone faced this problem ?
Have you any solution or workaround ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change workspace setting : build location => relative to workspace.
2. go to : build phase > pre build nativescript and then add one or more "output files" according to the errors in the previous build.

Comment: What does that look like? Do you just add the file name?

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment due to insufficient reputation points, but I am wondering if you know of an environmental variable that can be used in the output files configuration (i.e. DERIVED_FILE_DIR, TARGET_TEMP_DIR or something else) that can make the solution a bit more robust.

Comment: Yes I have seen this, I'll think about it for the next build thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. In Xcode. Go to File tab on the top bar =» Workspace Settings
2. Change the Location to Workspace-relative Location
3. Go to Build Phases tab => NativeScript PreBuild section
4. Add a new line o the Output files according to your error message
5. Press Cmd + Shift + K
6. Re-run your build.

Comment: More details needed to improve this answer. Step 4 is unclear.